# Trouble with replacing potentials for cc sources

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

I'm studying JFET transistors, and I'm having trouble with two things:
the electric potentials on the following circuits.
Writing the voltage Vds in function of Vdd, Id and Rd.
[image]

For example, for the N type (the one on the left), if I wanted to replace the +Vdd potential for a cc source, how would it be? I tried skechting it below, but I'm not sure about it.

[image]

If someone could explain this to me, or at least point me some references I would be grateful.

Also, for my second doubt, how can I write these equations using  Kirchhoff's voltage law?

Assuming Vds positive, for the N type I got +Vds -Rd*Id + Vdd = 0
Vds = Rd*Id + Id, but the book is telling me that it should be Vds = Vdd - Id*Rd

Thank you very much.

Comment: convert to a small-signal model, if you want gain. Otherwise find a diagram of the I_V plot, for Idrain versus Vdrain, with incremental Gate voltage steps.

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary FET, you need the equivalent (perhaps from a datasheet) of this plot shown below for a bipolar

[image]

Given the resistor has 12 volts when current is Zero, and 4.2mA when voltage is zero, the resistor value must be 12/0.00042 = ?